# Notify users paid version of app is available

Tags: android

I am launching a paid version of my app. I want to notify the current users of the paid version being available now. How do I give a one time notification to the users about it. The only constraint is that this alert/notification should be launched only once. In C, I would have done it using static variable. Here should I do it onCreate? But if app is killed by the OS, the next time app starts onCreate would be called and that would result in the same notification again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe u can save the variable in SharedPrefrence. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am using shared preferences for other things. Wonder why I didnt think of it for this purpose as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SharedPreferences, see following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultPreferences(this);
   if(prefs.getBoolean("not_notified", true))
   {
       //display alert
       prefs.edit().putBoolean("not_notified", false).commit();
   }
```